# My home partition is out of space and I have dual boot

Tags: 18.04

my home partition is going out of space. What is the best solution based on my current situation? I have dual boot on my system and here is the photo of my drives.

[Image of my drive using GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14CPZ.png)

Comment: Do you plan to continue using Windows partitions?

Comment: Your partitions make no sense. Home much smaller than root for starters and also a huge swap that isn't needed at all with 18.04 as it uses swapfile instead.

Comment: You probably don't need that much swap, you could use swap-file instead of swap-partition, you have plenty of space in your `/`-partition.

Comment: Yes I do plan to keep my windows partition.

Comment: GabrielaGarcia, What do you suggest as far as sizes for partitions?

Comment: mook765, do you have any link as far as instructions to do the adjustment and use swapfile instead of swap partition?

Answer (score 1):

First, the "key" icon beside the lines for `sda5`, `sda6` and `sda7` show that you booted from the disk and those partitions are mounted. You cannot change mounted partitions and you cannot unmount partitions you booted from. You MUST boot from some other medium - Live USB, CD, ... Search for "Ubuntu Live" and "Gparted Live".

Then, once you've booted from the Live USB and run `gparted`, it should be simple to expand `/dev/sda7`, `/home` into the adjacent 814.34 MiB.

Comment: Expanding _/dev/sda7_ to "adjacent" 0.8 GB sized partition would be of not much use.